# Showing that every point of an hyperboloid is of a certain form

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

Let $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be such that 
$$
            x^2+y^2-a^2z^2=c^2
$$
I want to show that any such $(x,y,z)$ can be written as

$$
           \cases{x=c\cos t-v\sin t
               \\ y=c\sin t+v\cos t
               \\ z=\frac{v}{a}}
$$
for some $t\in[0,2\pi[$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried the following:

We can always take $v=az\in\mathbb{R}$. Also, using this we get
$$
              x^2+y^2=v^2+c^2
$$
and we know that a parametrization of such a circle is
$$
               \cases{x = \sqrt{v^2+c^2}\cos t
                      \\ y = \sqrt{v^2+c^2}\sin t}
$$
(so for any $x,y$ we can find $t$ such that this happens).

Does this prove it? It is a little foggy for me.

**EDIT**: I think I got it all wrong, after all: I need to show that my initial expressions of $x,y$ parametrizes the circle, not just find some other expression...

Comment: Fill in your parametrisation for x,y,z in the original equation and see what you get. This should give you a first indication whether you are correct or false.

Comment: Yes, but it does not prove it... That would show that any point of my parametrization is in the hyperboloid, but not the reciprocal (which is what I want)

Comment: I know.That's why I said a first indication.